# What are these bugs ?

Tags: species-identification

[image]

There are a lot of these little bugs in my backyard. The floor, walls, the bbq island.

Are they hurtful to my dogs ?

What are these ?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the size of the insects as well as your geographical location and the season(s) when you see those them? That could help to identify them.